# Turn-by-Turn Navigation instruction from pgRouting Heading Android

Tags: android, pgrouting

I am using pgRouting request so i get the heading result of each edge.
I want to show turn by turn message when the distance between my current position and the start of the next edge is less than 50 meters.
I do this inside the onLocationChanged method. But i have lag because the code is executed each millisecond due to location manager.
Please i need help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a write up on how to generate driving instructions that I wrote about a few years ago. This how process can be built into a few stored procedures in the database to make it easier to deal with. pgrouting has no canned off the self solution for this.

https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/Driving-Direction-Instructions

Comment: Thank you it's very helpful